# ImageProcessor.Plugins.WebP - Cannot load libwebp.dll

Tags: c#, windows, imageprocessor

I have implemented ImageProcessor in our CMS (.net Framework) to convert images to webp.

I works fine on development PC and on testserver with Windows Server 2017.

On our current production server with Windows Server 2012 i get an "Cannot load libwebp.dll" exception.

In some forums and on and https://imageprocessor.org/imageprocessor/plugins/webp/ I can read could be related to installation of Windows C++ Redistributable which includes MSVCR120.DLL.

Even though i follow all instructions i still get the exception "Cannot load libwebp.dll""

Can anyone give me an solution.

Comment: You probably need to install libwebp.dll following https://developers.google.com/speed/webp/download

Comment: I have downloaded the source and compiled it according to https://developers.google.com/speed/webp/docs/compiling
Im not sure where i should place the libwebp.dll. I put it in both the \bin and \windows\system

Comment: libwebp is bundled. It's definitely Windows C++ Redistributable.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this?

Comment: yes, im using Imageprocessor to create WebP images with Wrapper for WebP format in C#. (MIT) Jose M. Piñeiro https://github.com/JosePineiro/WebP-wrapper

AND placed the dll both in root and in bin